# How can I test Netword Error by using Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I wrote a program that fetches data from the Internet.

```
public class GetDataService {

  public List<String> getData()  {
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
    URL url = new URL("http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip.txt");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
      String a = line;
      lines.add(a);
      }
      bufferedReader.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Can not making the request to the URL.");
    }
    return lines;
  }
}
```

Now I want to test network error by using Mockito. How can I do it? Also, is my code good? Any suggestions to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way :

```
when(mockUsingNetwork.doSomeNetworkAction()).thenReturn(new SomeNetworkError());
```

SomeNetworkError such as ConnectException for sockets for example

for your case it will be some thing like :

```
    URL url = Mockito.mock(URL.class);
    when(url.openConnection()).thenThrow(new IOException());
```